# How to securely save and send login username/password?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, authentication

I have a server application accepting login by multiple instances/users of a client application, over internet/socket connection. Usernames and passwords will be saved in a database on the server. But how do I save them securely? And how can authentication and sending of username/password from client be done securely? Currently I send everything as plain text strings.

There will be streaming data (financial; stock prices) between server/client, but this data is not critical, so I don't really see the need to secure that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must do https for the transaction and store password using SHA-1 hash and salt.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29

Add some examples :

http://www.obviex.com/samples/hash.aspx

http://www.aspheute.com/english/20040105.asp

http://csharptest.net/?p=470

Comment: That is, (Clarification) don't store the passwords at all, store only a hash of the password.

Comment: Thanks! Will I still be able to view and set/change the password, as administrator of the server application?

Comment: Yes, but you can't retrieve the user password, you can only reset it :)

Answer (score 1):

You could

- Store a hash of the password with salt within the database
- Connect the client to the server using ssl (at least for the login operation)