# ViewModel data being passed in address bar

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I have my change password controler.
The user changes the password and clicks submit.
I have my viewmodel of person p. 
I am not passing it at all to my success page.

```
return View("succsessFulLogin");
```

And still I am getting

```
http://localhost:50010/Password/ChangePassword?AccountName=username&CurrentPassword=currentPassValue&NewPassword=newPassValue&NewPasswordCheck=newCheckPassValue
```

In the address bar

this is my code on the page:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ChangePassword", "Password", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AccountName)
    <br />
    <div>
        <h4>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.CurrentPassword)</h4> @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.CurrentPassword, new { onkeydown = "capLock(event);" } ) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CurrentPassword)
    </div>
    <br />
    <div>
        <h4>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.NewPassword)</h4> @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.NewPassword, new { onkeydown = "capLock(event);" }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.NewPassword)
    </div>
    <br />
    <div>
        <h4>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.NewPasswordCheck)</h4> @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.NewPasswordCheck, new { onkeydown = "capLock(event);" }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.NewPasswordCheck)
    </div>
    <br />
    <p>
        <button class="btn-lg" type="submit">@Global.SAVE</button>
    </p>
}
```

Comment: `return View("succsessFulLogin");` does just that - it returns a view named `succsessFulLogin.cshtml` for the current url. You need to redirect using `return RedirectToAction("succsessFulLogin");`

Comment: And NEVER submit to a GET method if your modifying data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you are using `HTTP GET` the browser send data in `URl` and in this way you have limitation up to `2048 characters`.

[know more about HTTPGET and HTTPPOST](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)

to keep your data secure and protected  change your method To POST Like this :

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("ChangePassword", "Password" FormMethod.Post, null))
{}
```

then Add `[HTTpPost]` to your `Action Method` in your `controller` , like :

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ChangePassword(yourmodel model){}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with OP's issue (although its good advice regarding using `[HttpPost]` method.

Comment: @StephenMuecke do you mean we don't need to add [HttpPost] ?

Comment: No, it should definitely be a POST as you have state. Iits just that the reason OP gets that url when they go to _my success page_ is that they have used `return View("succsessFulLogin");` when they should be using `return RedirectToAction("succsessFulLogin"). Using `return View()` does not change the url (which included that query string because of the incorrect `FormMethod.Get` as you have stated)

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with osman Rahimi.

Using HTTP POST is **in no way** more secure than HTTP GET! As long as you're passing everything as clear text over http, you can read anything passed to and from the server, even if it isn't shown in the address bar. If you want to check me yourself, all you have to do is download [fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler), check the request and responses your page generates and see for yourself.

The proper way to transmit passwords on the net is to make sure you're using SSL and hashing the passwords. I am by no means an expert on the subject, but I think you'll find need in these answers:

1. [Securely Transfer User Entered Password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22912019/securely-transfer-user-entered-password)
2. [How should password be transfered for logon in Asp.net Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29792653/how-should-password-be-transfered-for-logon-in-asp-net-identity)
3. [How to securely save and send login username/password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442530/how-to-securely-save-and-send-login-username-password)

Comment: Ok maybe it needs to be encrypted but he is still right about the post

Comment: POST may be the correct method for you to use in this case, but the statement that POST "keep you data secure and protected" is false. As long as your passing anything as clear text anything can potentially read it.

Comment: @CKII when we use `POST` information will not be saved in the user's history  and clients don't see password in `Address bar`. using Http post it is not enough and be sure we need more security but for this approach it's better to use `Httppost`

Comment: When you're talking security, you're trying to prevent other people seeing the confidential information the user is sending. letting the user see the password he himself just entered, doesn't have much impact in that regard. Again, maybe POST is the better method for this situation. But it's not due to security.

Comment: @CKII yes , I agree with you, thank you for your information